# Make S3 Bucket Public Using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to expose my bucket to the public using terraform. What am I doing wrong.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "My_bucket" {
  bucket = "my-test-bucket-for-vpc-endpoints"
  tags = {
    Name = "My bucket"
  }
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "example_bucket_acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.id
  acl    = "public-read"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.id
}
```

Comment: "What am I doing wrong" - why do you think you do something wrong? Any errors? Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the below block

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.My_bucket.id
}
```